# Don't remember the name of a Java case tool where you can wire components

Tags: java

I saw an ads some weeks ago about such a case tool with a free community edition but I don't remember the name.

Does someone knows something like this ?

Comment: You don't mean Spring do you?

Comment: Spring is not a case tool it's a framework :). I mean by case tool something like UML IDE except it's not for UML.

Comment: If it doesn't produce UML, what does it produce?  Do you remember?

Comment: it produces java code by wiring java components which wasNT uml, it was more like wiring electric components :)

Comment: Visual Age used to do something like that, but I don't think it exists anymore.  I will be interested to see if you remember!

Comment: Visual Age is antiquated this one is brand new ... so new nobody seems to have never heard of it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wao I found it finally:

http://www.intrinsarc.com/

Answer (score 1):

You mean JUDE (now called Astah)?

Comment: No it wasn't UML Tool it was more like an electric-like wire of java components

Answer (score 0):

[Poseidon](http://www.gentleware.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

Design tool and UML CASE tool [Visual Paradigm](http://www.visual-paradigm.com)? They have a free community edition... :-)

Comment: I think we're going to get hit if we mention UML one more time :)

Comment: @britishmutt I won't dare so ;)

Comment: Well I'm also looking for UML but not in this thread :) I'm trying to install this http://www.softwareideas.net/ without success though.